# Python error access is denied

Tags: python-2.7

Esta dando este erro ao tentar rodar o projeto:
antes disso eu havia instalado o python 2.6 na maquina ... mas já possuía o python 2.7 será que isso pode ter causado o erro ?

> [Error 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs\mysql_python-1.2.4-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\_mysql.pyd'
>
> The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:
>
> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python-Eggs
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory? 
>   You can change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE
>   environment variable to point to an accessible directory.

Alguém já passou por isso ?? sabe ou tem uma ideia de como posso resolver ?

Comment: Esse erro deu quando? Você estava tentando instalar algo? Ou foi durante a execução de algum outro programa? Favor editar sua pergunta esclarecendo o contexto no qual esse erro ocorreu.

Comment: Eu não sei te responder, mesmo com as novas informações ("compilar o projeto"? que eu saiba python não se compila...), mas já deu pra ter alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo: 1) talvez você esteja sim executando o python errado; se você - ou algum outro código indiretamente iniciado - estiver usando o `python.exe` que está no `PATH`, este pode não ser o mesmo Python que você deseja que seja executado. Outra opção é ser algo envolvendo o `PYTHONPATH`. 2) Caso o problema não seja esse, e o Python for mesmo o correto, você deve tê-lo instalado como administrador, não como usuário comum.

Comment: Onde posso encontrar este path ? sou leigo em python e estou pegando um sistema que outro programador deixou pra trás.. o sistema utiliza django

Comment: Outra opção - se estou interpretando a mensagem de erro corretamente - é que você instalou um binário pra fazer a interface do python com o mysql em modo administrador, e agora está tentando executar um código que usa esse binário em modo usuário comum. P.S. O `PATH` é uma variável de ambiente do Windows. Como achá-lo depende da versão do windows, mas se você digitar no console `echo %path%` você pode ver seu valor. P.P.S. Dificilmente o problema está no django, mas me diz como você está executando? (`runserver` ou via webserver externo, ex. apache)

Comment: Então.. o sistema é em cima do python27 eu estou debugando com o pydev ... via apache ... este erro começou ocorrer depois que instalaram o python 2.6 no computador

Comment: ih, eu não sei nada sobre o pydev... :( Vou escrever uma resposta genérica, pra você tomar pé da situação, e quem sabe orientar na busca de uma solução. Se não resolver, o jeito vai ser esperar alguém que esteja familiarizado com essa ferramenta vir aqui e responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você possui duas versões do Python instalado no mesmo computador, em geral eles convivem bem lado a lado, se instalados corretamente. No caso do Windows, há algumas coisas a se levar em consideração:

- Uma entrada de registro distinta será criada para cada uma delas (ex.: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Python \ PythonCore \ 2.7`). Eu *acho* que isso vale inclusive pra versões menores (`2.6` vs. `2.7`), mas não tenho certeza.

  Dentro dessa entrada há uma chave `PythonPath` mostrando onde o Python está instalado. Se possível, verifique isso (via `regedit`) e se certifique que a versão que você está tentando executar está acessível (se ela estiver dentro da pasta home do administrador, provavelmente você só poderá acessar se executar o sistema como administrador).
- Às vezes um deles vai parar na variável de ambiente `PATH` - de modo a permitir executar o Python escrevendo simplesmente `python` em vez do caminho completo para o executável. Pode ser que a versão errada esteja no path, e seu sistema esteja chamando ela em vez da versão correta.

Além disso, se seu sistema é um site/aplicação Django implantado via Apache, é importante que o Apache encontre a versão correta do python. Pelo que você descreveu, antes quando só havia uma versão funcionava bem, mas depois quando a outra foi instalada parou de funcionar. Isso sugere fortemente que a segunda versão sobrescreveu o/ganhou precedência no `PATH` e portanto o Apache está tentando utilizá-la em vez da antiga.

A forma mais comum de integração Python/Apache é via `mod_wsgi`. Também é possível fazê-lo através do obsoleto `mod_python` e, no caso do Django, de algumas outras formas também (ex.: `FastCGI`). Descubra qual delas seu projeto está usando, e busque as informações necessárias para se especificar um python dentre vários. No `mod_wsgi`, por exemplo, é através da propriedade [`WSGIPythonExecutable`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonExecutable). Ela deve ser setada no arquivo de configurações do Apache. *Talvez* seu erro tenha alguma relação com [`WSGIPythonEggs`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonEggs) em vez disso (a mensagem de erro falava em algo envolvendo a "egg cache"). Outras configurações que podem ser úteis são: [`WSGIPythonPath`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) e [`WSGIPythonHome`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) (na dúvida, sete todas elas, de acordo com a documentação).

**Atualização:** acabei de me lembrar que o suporte pra `mod_wsgi` no Windows é fraco... Pelo que li da documentação linkada acima, a maioria dessas propriedades não são bem suportadas nesse ambiente. Se for o caso, receio que sua única saída será mesmo instalar uma única versão do Python...

Por fim, se o problema não for no Apache, mas na ferramenta que você está usando para depurar `pydev`, será preciso ver nas configurações dela como especificar a versão correta a ser usada. Quando a isso, receio não poder ajudar...

Comment: Entrei no regedit e fui no pythonpath está setado com este valor C:\Python33\Lib;C:\Python33\DLLs ... também tem o python33 na maquina..

Comment: @WisnerOliveira Cara, que salada! :P Felizmente, dá pra contornar tudo isso. A propósito, havia um erro na minha resposta, a propriedade certa é `WSGIPythonExecutable` - embora as demais (`...Path`, `...Home` e `...Eggs`) também possam ser importantes, não sei.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma..desinstalei todas versões do python e limpei o registro depois instalei a versão 2.7 ai funcionou normal... Obrigado pela ajuda cara :D

**Atualizado:** Não foi por causa das versões que deu este erro e sim por causa de uma nova IDE que eu resolvi testar... chama pyCharm ela é otima .. só não sei porque aconteceu isso.. tipo se eu reinstalo e rodo o projeto no eclipse vai normal.. ai se eu rodar uma vez no pyCharm vai dar um erro (que no caso é esse) e depois começa a gerar este erro ai depois tanto pro eclipse quanto pro pyCharm.